# Getting an error while using format- number - NaN

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have to select the value of v1 which has match as V0 and (Need to make a 13 digit number , also remove the decimal point)
I am getting NaN.
Please guide.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
<xsl:template match="A">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(B[match = V0]/v1 * 100,'0000000000000')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

INPUT:

```
<A>
<B>
    <match>V0</match>
    <v1>34.56</v1>
</B>
<B>
    <match>V1</match>
    <v1>34.54</v1>
</B>
```

Expected - 0000000003456

Actual - NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(B[match = V0]/v1 * 100,'0000000000000')"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(B[match = 'V0']/v1 * 100,'0000000000000')"/>
```

And the rest will follow.

**Output is:**

```
000000003456
```

You forgot to put your element value into single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, wanted to know one thing , if the value itself is not present in input, then it will give output as NaN. how to avoid that?

Comment: You can use (the XPath-2.0) if-then-else to even check if the value can be cast to a double datatype. First, add this namespace to the stylesheet element: `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`. Then use this expression in the `select="..."`: `if (B[match = 'V0']/v1 castable as xs:double) then format-number(B[match = 'V0']/v1 * 100,'0000000000000') else 'Not present'`.